# Listview displays wrong data

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple chat app in Android Studio + Firebase and I am displaying the user email, the message and the date and time. The problem is even when the chat room is empty with no messages the date of the list view items still shows and it displays 01-01-1970 for some weird reason.

Screenshot of the problem

[image]

```
chatMessage.setText(model.getChatMessage());
author.setText(model.getAuthor());
chatTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getChatTime()));
```

[image: When I send message]

```
public class chatAppGetter {

private String chatMessage;
private String author;
private String username;
private long chatTime;



public chatAppGetter(String chatMessage, String author) {
    this.chatMessage = chatMessage;
    this.author = author;

    chatTime = new Date().getTime();
}

public chatAppGetter() {
}

public String getChatMessage() {
    return chatMessage;
}

public void setChatMessage(String chatMessage) {
    this.chatMessage = chatMessage;
}

public long getChatTime() {
    return chatTime;
}

public void setChatTime(long chatTime) {
    this.chatTime = chatTime;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
}


ListView messageList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<chatAppGetter>(this,    chatAppGetter.class, R.layout.chat_items, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, chatAppGetter model, int position) {

            TextView chatMessage, author, chatTime;
            chatMessage = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);
            author = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.chat_user);
            chatTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.chat_time);
```

EDIT:

Question solved. I had to create a separate branch of database for the messages.

Comment: provide a local time zone , or yo can simply use jodatime date format

Comment: The problem is even if the user haven't send a message the date still displays for some reason so weird. Basically, I am using a Dateformat.format("") string to define my format and because its a string it gets displayed in the listview even without a user sending a message.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: I added some of the code where I think the problem is. I think it is because of this ("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)" it displays the string anyway even when a message isnt posted.

Comment: The list view shouldn't display list view items if the user hasn't send a message.

Comment: I think ur problem can be  2: 1st that u forgot to delete the android:text from a textview from ur xml layout for that item list. take a look to that, i see it repeats the same date so maybe could be that or under your adapter check if the message is not empty and then set  the text to the textview

Comment: I ll look onto that later,first fix the date ! right

Comment: @Catluc there is no android text in the textview.

Comment: Then please post ur  code for that list adapter!

Comment: @Catluc done. now

Comment: U post only a part, it looks like copy&paste problem!

Comment: Are you using custom adapter or ArrayAdapter? plz share your adapter code.

Comment: The problem is simple is just that the listview displays items even though the user hasn't typed a message thats it. It should not display anything until someone sends a message.

Comment: I think your firebase location has some dummy data

Comment: The data is not dummy but i found the problem actually thank you man. The problem is that the listview takes all the data from the database and tries to display it.

Comment: I fixed it guys finally. I made a child in the database called messages and used that to store the messages and not in the main database.

Comment: Hi @Kovachx. You could just go ahead and add in your *own answer* (with as much details as you can provide, so that it might help someone in the future) for your question then mark it as the accepted answer, instead of editing out the whole question out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();       
  int  hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);    
  if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM){
     am_pm = "AM";
  }else if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM) 
     am_pm = "PM"; 

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());        
    Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

//Now use the formattedDate and pass this into setText of yours.
//Go for JodaTime ,makes life easy

Comment: I think the problem is not the date and time its the list view it displays items even when the user hasn't send a message so weird.

Comment: Thats fine but the problem is the list view displays date even when a user hasn't posted a message.